# Determine if a callback is in progress (DevExpress)

Tags: ajax, callback, devexpress

I am looking for a way to determine if any of my DevExpress ASPxGridView controls are currently in a callback state.  I assume those controls use standard ASP.NET callback procedure but I am not sure.  If that is the case there might be an ASP.NET (non-DevExpress) method of determining this.

Specifically, I need to disable a submit button when a callback is occuring because clicking it during a callback causes the page to enter a bad state and give low-level ASP.NET 'Invalid postback or callback argument' event validation errors on future callbacks/submits.

I am using jQuery and the .ajaxSend() and similar global jQuery AJAX methods aren't capturing the callback.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to determine the state when ASPxGridView processes a callback request in any of the following way:

1) Utilize the client-side **ASPxClientGridView.InCallback()** method (use the **ASPxGridView's ClientInstanceName** property to get access to the client-side programmatic ASPxGridView's object);

2) Handle the client-side **ASPxClientGridView.BeginCallback** event to store the information indication that the DevExpress' callback has started and the client-side **ASPxClientGridView.EndCallback** event to clear this state. I suggest you use the invisible **ASPxGlobalEvents** component and handle its client-side event (with the same names) to handle this state.

Comment: I'm more specifically looking for some sort of global flag in DevExpress or ASP.NET. I figure that would be more reliable than using ASPxGlobalEvents events to keep a counter of callbacks in progress.  That said, the pointer to ASPxGlobalEvents was helpful.  Thank you.